# Reactive UI Routing and UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, reactiveui

I am struggling with ReactiveUI routing for my UWP Navigation View. Since Navigation View Item does not implement command I use ItemInvoked event and execute my command in my view model. Unfortunately, I am unable to show another page in the view. I was using the official tutorial and also  [Reactive UI UWP Example](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI.Samples/tree/main/uwp/routing/ReactiveUI.UwpRouting). When using breakpoint I can see that my command is executed but nothing happens. I have no clue how to debug this more. Did anyone implement Navigation View wit ReactiveUI Routing?
My code: [My repo](https://github.com/mikart143/UWP-SLACK)

@Edit

> POCOObservableForProperty: The class InwentarzRzeczowy.UWP.Views.MainView property ViewModel is a POCO type and won't send change notifications, WhenAny will only return a single value!

> POCOObservableForProperty: The class InwentarzRzeczowy.UWP.Views.MainView property RoutedViewHost is a POCO type and won't send change notifications, WhenAny will only return a single value!

Comment: Are you implementing Inotifypropertychanged

Comment: Yes both view models implement INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: The two properties that aren't though are `MainView.RoutedViewHost` and `MainView.ViewModel` properties.

Comment: The best way to do that on UWP is to use a DependencyProperty https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/blob/a6c5dcf4f0ce82a9c0c8b05d7c78f80cd57028d1/src/ReactiveUI/Platforms/windows-common/ReactiveUserControl.cs#L100

Comment: You can always use Sextant (related to ReactiveUI).  I got that working with NavigationView just fine...  https://github.com/limefrogyank/Sextant/tree/master/src/Sextant.UWP

Comment: @GlennWatson please post an answer, I want to accept this. That helped me. I was looking at other examples and this get me wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the conversation we had in Slack, posting the solution here as well. With ReactiveUI routing, you have to either register the views into `Splat.Locator.CurrentMutable` before using the router (see [View Location](https://www.reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/view-location/#registering-new-views)) or write a custom view locator that matches your view models and returns the views (see [Routing](https://www.reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/routing/#view-location)). The latter option expects you to implement the `IViewLocator` interface and assign it to `RoutedViewHost.ViewLocator` property. So, in C# code we generally have this:

```cs
public class YourViewLocator : IViewLocator
{
    public IViewFor ResolveView<T>(T viewModel, string contract = null) => viewModel switch
    {
        NewEntryViewModel _ => new NewEntryView(),
        // Also match other routable view models...
        // The RoutedViewHost will initialize the ViewModel 
        // properties of your views automatically.
        _ => throw new System.NotImplementedException()
    };
}
```

And in XAML markup we have this:

```xml
<reactiveUi:RoutedViewHost Router="{Binding Router}">
    <reactiveUi:RoutedViewHost.ViewLocator>
        <yourAssembly:YourViewLocator />
    </reactiveUi:RoutedViewHost.ViewLocator>
</reactiveUi:RoutedViewHost>
```

Also, it is important to initialize the `IViewFor.ViewModel` property for the root view. This could be done in the constructor of your view right after a call to `this.InitializeComponent()`, or in the composition root of your application.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need a `.Subscribe()` after the AddPage.Execute() command in your event handler.  I'm doing this from memory though and I remember something like that tripping me up.

Comment: I found this earlier and still does not work. I edited my question. I found some warnings in my log.